# Should using different unit cells lead to different band diagrams?

Tags: crystals, electronic-band-theory

I am interested in hexagonal (triangular) lattice i.e. the structure is metal rods at the center of each hexagon. Two different unit cells that I think can be used are shown in the figure. My question is:

1. Are their Brillouin zones different (for the hexagonal unit cell, the brillouin zone is a hexagon rotated by 90 deg(w.r.t. the real space hexagon); will that be further rotated by any angle if I use the other unit cell?)?
2. I tried to calculate photonic band structure using those two unit cells. They are giving slightly different band diagrams. If it is expected, why is so? I also observed the difference only for TE modes.

[image: Two kind of unit cells used for band-structure calculation (triangular lattice)]